# LYTD dax time intelligence

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have :

```
Quantity Sold LY = CALCULATE([Total Quantity Sold], DATEADD(Dates[Date], -1, YEAR))
```

and I want to calculate the quantity sold last year to date :

```
Quantity Sold LYTD = CALCULATE([Quanity Sold LY], DATESYTD(Dates[Date]))
```

BUT, when I combine these two and write it as follow, the results are totally different:

```
total quantity sold last 1 year =  
VAR L1Y=  CALCULATE([Total Quantity Sold], DATEADD(Dates[Date], -1, YEAR)) 
return 

CALCULATE(L1Y, DATESYTD(Dates[Date]))
```

can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the variable `L1Y`, it is stored as a constant.

Suppose `L1Y` evaluates to be 152. Then your last calculation would be equivalent to

```
CALCULATE(152, DATESYTD(Dates[Date]))
```

I think you want to do something like this:

```
CALCULATE([Total Quantity Sold], DATEADD(DATESYTD(Dates[Date]), -1, YEAR))
```

Comment: Thank you Alexis
I completely forgot that after creating a variable it is creating as a constant !!!! :(